# How can I get records from one table which do not exist in a related table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this `users` table:

[image: users]

and this `relationships` table:

[image]

So each user is paired with another one in the `relationships` table.

Now I want to get a list of `users` which are not in the `relationships` table, in either of the two columns (`user_id` or `pair_id`).

**How could I write that query?**

First try:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships
ON users.id = relationships.user_id
WHERE relationships.user_id IS NULL;
```

Output:

[image]

This is should display only 2 results: 5 and 6. The result 8 is not correct, as it already exists in `relationships`. Of course I'm aware that the query is not correct, how can I fix it?

- I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare to both values in the `on` statement:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     relationships r
     ON u.id = r.user_id or u.id = r.pair_id
WHERE r.user_id IS NULL;
```

In general, `or` in an `on` clause can be inefficient.  I would recommend replacing this with two `not exists` statements:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relationships r WHERE u.id = r.user_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relationships r WHERE u.id = r.pair_id);
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the alternative more efficient version

Comment: BTW, this is in general terms called a "left anti-join".

Comment: @David . . . I think this may be faster than Erwin's answer (which I say with some trepidation) if you have indexes on both `relationships(user_id)` and `relationships(pair_id)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff even having one more select?

Comment: @David . . . Many databases will not take advantage of two indexes for an `in` or `or` clause in a correlated subquery.  I do not know if Postgres would take advantage of indexes in the formulation in Erwin's answer, but I am skeptical.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok you convinced me, and also the number of votes on your answer. Switching the accepted answer to yours :)

Comment: @David: Why don't you just test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`? Of course, either of these queries is going to use matching indexes in Postgres. It depends on various details which of the queries will be faster. Mine is shorter and more versatile.

Comment: @David . . . Erwin is right.  You should test the answers and see which gives you the performance/execution plan that you want.

Comment: Both queries are fast enough for my needs. Gordon's query has 9 steps (2x Hash anti join, 2x Hash cond, 3x Seq scan, 2x Hash), while Erwin's has 5 (1x Nested loop anti join, 1x Join filter, 2x Seq scan, 1x Materialize). The final runtime is barely the same for both. It's very difficult to choose one. I will choose Gordon's because it seems clearer to me, although Erwin's uses one less select, both are very good pieces of code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I like the set operators

```
select id from users
  except
select user_id from relationships
  except
select pair_id from relationships
```

or

```
select id from users
  except
(select user_id from relationships
   union
 select pair_id from relationships
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of:
[Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

I suppose this will be simplest and fastest:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   relationships r
   WHERE  u.id IN (r.user_id, r.pair_id)
   );
```

In Postgres, `u.id IN (r.user_id, r.pair_id)` is just short for:`(u.id = r.user_id OR u.id = r.pair_id)`.
The expression is transformed that way internally, which can be observed from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

To clear up speculations in the comments: Modern versions of Postgres are going to use matching indexes on `user_id`, and / or `pair_id` with this sort of query.

Comment: +1 This seems very efficient to me, and using just 2 selects. It also lets tweak the select freely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select u.id
from users u
where u.id not in (select r.user_id from relationships r) 
and u.id not in (select r.pair_id from relationships r)
```